# WPF bool dependency property C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I create a simple bool dependency property `IsInput`. This value can only be set to `true` or `false` when the class is created in code. Seems rather simple but ive searched around online and haven't found a clear example.

I've seen examples like this one below online but I'm not quite clear on what I would duplicate to create my own bool dependency property correctly.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AncestorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Ancestor", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MyItem),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Ancestor_PropertyChanged));

/// <summary>
/// Event raised when 'Ancestor' property has changed.
/// </summary>
private static void Ancestor_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyItem c = (MyItem)d;
    c.UpdateHotspot();
}
```

Comment: Just read documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of the Register method is the type of the property, i.e. `bool`, while the third parameter is the so-called *owner type*, which is the type that declares the property (`MyControl` in the example below).

For a complete dependency property declaration you also need to declare the "wrapper" property with a getter and a setter that call the dependency property's `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInputProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsInput", typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IsInputPropertyChanged));

/// <summary>
/// CLR wrapper for the 'IsInput' dependency property.
/// </summary>
public bool IsInput
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInputProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsInputProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Callback called when 'IsInput' property has changed.
/// </summary>
private static void IsInputPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool b = (bool)e.NewValue;
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Not sure what should be wrong about. Could you please explain?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597500(v=vs.100).aspx): "*ownerType*: The owner type that is registering the dependency property."

Comment: Take a look at [WPF Dependency Properties: Why do I need to specify an Owner Type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868768/wpf-dependency-properties-why-do-i-need-to-specify-an-owner-type), it is almost always correct to use the actual owner `Type` rather than a different class.

Comment: @Lukazoid Actually, it is never correct to use any other type. Besides that there is no reason to do so. If you declare a property in a different type than the one where the property is applied, use an attached property.

Comment: @Clemens That is true, I would be using an attached property. I assumed the accepted and upvoted answer on my link was correct and just something I had never used.